# Why am I getting a Type Error: Range can't be coerced into Integer for line 11, if max == ele % 0?

Tags: ruby, typeerror

The following returns a Type Error in my conditional within the do block
Range can't be coerced into Integer

```
def coprime?(num_1, num_2)
    min = [num_1, num_2].min
    max = [num_1, num_2].max

    [2..min].each do |ele|
        if max % ele == 0
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

p coprime?(25, 12)    # => true
p coprime?(7, 11)     # => true
p coprime?(30, 9)     # => false
p coprime?(6, 24)     # => false
```

Comment: `min,  max  =  [num_1, num_2].minmax`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because ranges in Ruby should have the form `(start..end)`. In your case `[2..min]` is an array with only one element, where that element is a range.

You can replace the `[]` with `()` to create a range from 2 to `min`:

```
(2..min).each do |ele|
  if max % ele == 0
    return true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`2..min` is a range, therefore `[2..min]` is actually an array with 1 element and the `ele` will be `2..min`

It should be `(2..min).each do |ele|` instead of `[2..min].each do |ele|`

Also you don't need to `return false` at the end just `false` is enough.